# Use prepaid cards in Europe with my Verizon S3 sch-i535?

Tags: uk, cellphones, pre-pay

I am going to England, Scotland, and Ireland soon for about 10 days.  I have a rooted Samsung Galaxy S3 (SCH-I535) on Verizon with Android 4.2.2.

I'd like to use voice + data (no SMS) over there using one prepaid card across all 3 countries, not using the VZW network at all.  I don't want Verizon to charge me anything extra.

Does anyone know if this is possible?  What company would sell the prepaid card, and what do I need to do to prepare?

Comment: I have the Verizon GS3 as well, and am tired of this nonsense from AT&T and Verizon. Nexus phone or naught for the future.

Answer (score 2):

While your hardware is perfectly capable, Verizon has crippled the software so [you cannot](http://news.cnet.com/8301-33620_3-57569438-278/turns-out-verizons-galaxy-s3-isnt-global-ready-after-all/) access data networks with a non-Verizon SIM card, and can only access some voice networks (at least, without a bit of hacking). And this is the "fixed" software that came with the Jelly Bean update.

Specifically, there is [no way to change the APN](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36237/add-an-apn-to-samsung-galaxy-s3-running-4-1-1) settings manually, and thus if you need to connect to a network other than Verizon's defaults, you are out of luck.

There are [various](http://www.droidforums.net/forum/droid-news/219929-need-your-verizon-galaxy-s-iii-world-phone-traveling-here-s-how.html) [guides](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=31095006&postcount=106) for adding support after ["root"-ing your phone](http://androidforums.com/international-galaxy-s3-all-things-root/443802-samsung-galaxy-s3-all-things-root-guide-last-updated-22-feb-2013-a.html), but rooting is a step I only advise for people who are very familiar and very comfortable with hacking their phones (which voids your warranty and insurance and if it goes awry, leaves you with a glossy brick).

Comment: Thanks. I rooted my S3 and now have Android 4.2.2 from AOKP.  Do you think voice, txt, and data will work on a prepaid card in Europe now?  Thanks!

Comment: @Ryan I linked to a couple of guides. The DF method seems to require more apps than XDA, but perhaps that's because it's a more "consumer-oriented" site if you will. I haven't tried either method myself, as I've been able to rely on WiFi + Skype thus far.